# reading json wrong when checking app updates

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the following code to check whether an update is available or not. But it gave me wrong version number. So, it seems an update is available when actually there's not.

```
enum VersionError: Error {
    case invalidResponse, invalidBundleInfo
}

static func isUpdateAvailable() throws -> Bool {
    guard let info = Bundle.main.infoDictionary,
        let currentVersion = info["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String,
        let identifier = info["CFBundleIdentifier"] as? String,
        let url = URL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/tr/lookup?bundleId=\(identifier)") else {
            throw VersionError.invalidBundleInfo
    }
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [.allowFragments]) as? [String: Any] else {
        throw VersionError.invalidResponse
    }
    if let result = (json["results"] as? [Any])?.first as? [String: Any], let version = result["version"] as? String {

        print("version: \(version)")   //writes 1.1
        print("currentVersion: \(currentVersion)") //writes 1.1.1
        return version != currentVersion
    }
    throw VersionError.invalidResponse
}
```

I downloaded the file manually and the version number there is 1.1.1. as it should be. But the code gives me 1.1. I couldn't find out what is wrong.

By the way, the update has just released today. I think it shouldn't be related with that.

The url: http://itunes.apple.com/tr/lookup?bundleId=com.sahin.lingustica

Comment: I use curl to fetch the URL you gave and I see data such as **"wrapperType":"software", "version":"1.1", "artistId":1219638872** inside the results.

Comment: Hmm.. I've opened it in Safari and it seems "version":"1.1.1"

Comment: Maybe something about cache??  I see that the headers mention Akamai.

Comment: I don’t know. It’s wrong in curl, too. And it’s correct as url in Safari, Chrome etc.

Comment: Interesting.  If I enter the following curl command, I get 1.1.1.  `curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/601.2.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.1 Safari/601.2.4 facebookexternalhit/1.1 Facebot Twitterbot/1.0" http://itunes.apple.com/tr/lookup?bundleId=com.sahin.lingustica`

Comment: (I just copied an agent string arbitrarily that I found online.)

Comment: In Postman, I get 1.1.1. It's very annoying. Can there be a problem in the code?

Comment: Given the two different curl results, my best guess is that the server is replying with different results for different clients.  You may need to get your data with a `URLRequest` so that you can supply a custom User-Agent header.

Comment: I tried the following function but still got same wrong result :
`(URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL, completionHandler: (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)` and this is my request: `var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("Content-Type", forHTTPHeaderField: "application/json")`

Comment: @D3sT checkout my answer

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't fix my problem. It's weird but after I create a new version 1.1.2 in ITunesConnect (not submitted, only as prepare for submission), the code started to write the version 1.1.1. I think it is a bug from the Apple side.

Comment: @D3sT Check out this, its working fine for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48717836/how-to-make-app-update-available-to-users-in-the-form-of-an-attractive-screen/48718114#48718114

Answer (score 0):

In your method have comparison problem for compare two version string use this

```
version.compare(currentVersion, options: .numeric) == .orderedDescending ? true : false
```

I have change in your method Try this

```
static func isUpdateAvailable() throws -> Bool {
    guard let info = Bundle.main.infoDictionary,
        let currentVersion = info["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String,
        let identifier = info["CFBundleIdentifier"] as? String,
        let url = URL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/tr/lookup?bundleId=\(identifier)") else {
            throw VersionError.invalidBundleInfo
    }
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [.allowFragments]) as? [String: Any] else {
        throw VersionError.invalidResponse
    }
    if let result = (json["results"] as? [Any])?.first as? [String: Any], let version = result["version"] as? String {

        print("version: \(version)")   //writes 1.1
        print("currentVersion: \(currentVersion)") //writes 1.1.1
        rreturn version.compare(currentVersion, options: .numeric) == .orderedDescending ? true : false
    }
    throw VersionError.invalidResponse
}
```

Comment: I checked again and yes, it returns false as it should be. But I think it doesn't solve the problem completely. For example, if the actual version in the App Store is 1.1.5 and I get 1.1.4 in the code, the current version of the user may be 1.1.4. So the method returns false but actually it should be true. I think the problem here is why I get the version from the json wrong

Comment: on that case  let version = result["version"]  value is 1.1.5 and current version 1.1.4 so yes update available

Comment: but the problem is when the actual version is 1.1.5, the code gives me version as 1.1.4.

Comment: " if the actual version in the App Store is 1.1.5 and I get 1.1.4 in the code" As per your code you must get 1.1.5 you need to recheck

Comment: I couldn't find out what I'm doing wrong. The code is as I posted. This code gives me 1.1.4 when the actual version is 1.1.5. But if I create a new version in itunes connect, for example 1.1.6 as prepare for submission, then the code started to give 1.1.5.

Comment: http://itunes.apple.com/tr/lookup?bundleId= this returns live application version not prepare for submission  version