# app to announce a new update

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to make the app announce a new update exists ...
I am notified of a new alert but the problem is that I do not control it .. It just informs nonstop even after I change the version in "appinfo.plist" which is in github
It goes like this

```
- (void)checkVersion {
    NSString *rawgitHistory = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"appinfo" ofType:@"plist"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    __block NSArray *gitHistory = [rawgitHistory componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul), ^{
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dev/myapp/master/appinfo.plist"]];
        // User isn't on a network, or the request failed
        if (data == nil) return;

        NSString *gitCommit = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        if (![gitHistory containsObject:gitCommit]){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Update Available!" message:@"An update is available! Please visit download the latest IPA!" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
                [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];
                [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
            });
        }
    });
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self checkVersion];
}
```

**appinfo.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Version</key>
    <string>1.0.4.1</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Could you explain what sort of data is contained in `gitHistory `?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>Version</key>
 <string>1.0.4.1</string>
</dict>
</plist>

Comment: What is this condition ? if (![gitHistory containsObject:gitCommit]){ . this will be executed everytime if gitHistory contains gitCommit.

Comment: What should I do please

Comment: Don't really understand what you hope to achieve by checking for the app version in this manner. There are open source libraries which can help you achieve this: https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Harpy

Comment: @testerbeta - This may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48717836/how-to-make-app-update-available-to-users-in-the-form-of-an-attractive-screen/48718114#48718114

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this a lot easier. Instead of comparing plist files, you can do the following:
Check the application's build number and also store the latest build number in your web service then compare these two values. If the app's build number is smaller than the build number in your web service, then show the alert.

```
-(void)checkVersion {

   //Get the current installed build number
   NSString *currentBuildID = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey: (NSString *)kCFBundleVersionKey];
   __block NSInteger currentBuildNumber = currentBuildID.integerValue;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("buildChecker", NULL), ^{

       NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your url to get build number"]];
       // User isn't on a network, or the request failed
       if (data == nil) return;

       NSString *latestBuild = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       //Compare the latest build number with app's build number
       if (currentBuildNumber < latestBuild.integerValue){
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
               UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Update Available!" message:@"An update is available! Please visit download the latest IPA!" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
               [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];
               [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
          });
       }
   });
}
```

You can set the build number of your app from your target's pane under General>Build
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSString *versionInAppStore;

    NSString *localAppVersion;


    -(void)appUpdater  {




    NSDictionary* infoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=%@",@"Your Bundle ID here"]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                            completionHandler:
                                  ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {


                                      NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];


                                      versionInAppStore = [[[jsonDict objectForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"version"];

                                      localAppVersion = infoDictionary[@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];




                                      if (versionInAppStore > localAppVersion) {

                                          UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"New version available (%@)",versionInAppStore] message:@"A new version of Keepmefit is available. Please update to new version now." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

                                          UIAlertAction* alertAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Update" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {


                                              NSString *iTunesLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your app store application link here"];

                                              UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

                                              [application openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];


                                          }];

                                          UIAlertAction *updateLater = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Update Later" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

                                          }];

                                          [alert addAction:alertAction];

                                          [alert addAction:updateLater];

                                          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                                              [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

                                          });



                                      }



                                  }];

    [task resume];



   }
```